# How to Improve the Appearance of Aligned Typewriter Text in a Minipage

Tags: minipage, alignment, text, typewriter, justification

Consider the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{ragged2e} 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{This is a minipage. The above line of commands justifies the text and centers the last line. Notice how "nice" it appears.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\spaceskip1em plus 1em \xspaceskip 1em plus 2em\relax
\texttt{I have, with the two above lines of commands, been able to justify the tttext in this minipage, as well as center the last line of output. This is what I want; however, the appearance does not seem as "nice" as the content of the above minipage.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

Although the second minipage produces what I am looking for---tttext both left and right justified with the last line of output centered---the appearance seems to pale in comparison to justified output of the first minipage.

I thought by invoking the `ragged2e` package; but upon doing so, aside from centering the last line of `texttt` text, it made matters a whole lot worse.

QUESTION: How may I (simply, if possible) improve the appearance of the `texttt` text justified output (e.g., reduce spacing between the lines, reduce the spacing between the words---to reduce the number of lines of output)?

I compile the code with `lualatex`

Thank you.

Comment: why use a monospace font if you are using variable word spaces so move characters off the monospace grid? Also by default hyphenation is disabled for monospace so you have to stretch space _a lot_ to justify text. Improving appearance doesn't seem possible given those constraints

Comment: `\hyphenchar\font=\`\-` would re-enable hyphenation

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Am I to attach `\hyphenchar\font=`\-` as part of another command? As is, I  have not been able to enable hyphenation.

Comment: see the comments under the accepted (??) answer. You could do as egreg shows in the other answer but using monospace this way is really weird, would you be better with latin modern variable width typewriter?

Comment: A monospaced font will *never* look good justified in a narrow column except by accident or if the text is carefully crafted.  You might instead want to consider `\centering`.  Off-topic: open quotes in environments using a `\tt` font should be entered using a double backtick.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As you have stretchy inter-word spaces, there is no monospaced character alignment you would be better to use a variable width typewriter font, as justifying monospace will always look awful.

lvmtt allows hyphenation and variable inter-word space by default so fewer settings are required.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
%\usepackage{ragged2e} 

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
  \textbf{This is a minipage. The above line of commands justifies the
    text and centers the last line. Notice how "nice" it appears.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
    \fontfamily{lmvtt}\selectfont
    I
    have, with the two above lines of commands, been able to justify
    the tttext in this minipage, as well as center the last line of
    output. This is what I want; however, the appearance does not seem
    as "nice" as the content of the above minipage.
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

No image today  but [see output here](https://texlive.net/run?%25!tex%20lualatex%0A%5Cdocumentclass%5B12pt%5D%7Bbook%7D%0A%5Cusepackage%7Bmicrotype%7D%0A%25%5Cusepackage%7Bragged2e%7D%20%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bdocument%7D%0A%5Cthispagestyle%7Bempty%7D%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7BLARGE%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bminipage%7D%7B5.75in%7D%5Cleftskip%5Cfill%5Crightskip-%5Cleftskip%5Cparfillskip%5Cstretch%7B2%7D%25%0A%20%20%5Ctextbf%7BThis%20is%20a%20minipage.%20The%20above%20line%20of%20commands%20justifies%20the%0A%20%20%20%20text%20and%20centers%20the%20last%20line.%20Notice%20how%20%22nice%22%20it%20appears.%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bminipage%7D%0A%5Cend%7BLARGE%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%0A%0A%5Cvspace*%7B25pt%7D%0A%0A%5Cbegin%7Bcenter%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7BLARGE%7D%0A%5Cbegin%7Bminipage%7D%7B5.75in%7D%5Cleftskip%5Cfill%5Crightskip-%5Cleftskip%5Cparfillskip%5Cstretch%7B2%7D%25%0A%20%20%20%20%5Cfontfamily%7Blmvtt%7D%5Cselectfont%0A%20%20%20%20I%0A%20%20%20%20have,%20with%20the%20two%20above%20lines%20of%20commands,%20been%20able%20to%20justify%0A%20%20%20%20the%20tttext%20in%20this%20minipage,%20as%20well%20as%20center%20the%20last%20line%20of%0A%20%20%20%20output.%20This%20is%20what%20I%20want;%20however,%20the%20appearance%20does%20not%20seem%0A%20%20%20%20as%20%22nice%22%20as%20the%20content%20of%20the%20above%20minipage.%0A%5Cend%7Bminipage%7D%0A%5Cend%7BLARGE%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bcenter%7D%0A%5Cend%7Bdocument%7D)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Along the lines of the above comments, this is a similar, but different approach:

Use `\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font=1}` in the preamble. (The font=1 allows a dash to be used when hyphenating; font=-1 permits hyphenation but with no dash.)

Also, diminishing the font size should also improve aesthetics.

Now, the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font=1}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{This is a minipage. The above line of commands justifies the text and centers the last line. Notice how "nice" it appears.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\spaceskip1em plus 1em \xspaceskip 1em plus 2em\relax
\texttt{This is a minipage. The above line of commands justifies the text and centers the last line. Notice how "nice" it appears.}
\end{minipage}
\end{large}
\end{center}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{large}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\spaceskip1em plus 1em \xspaceskip 1em plus 2em\relax
\texttt{This is a minipage. Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious}
\end{minipage}
\end{large}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

produces the output:

[image]

Since there was nothing to hyphenate in the second paragraph, I have put in a third to illustrate that the code *does* produce hyphenation.

Comment: ``\hyphenchar\font=`\-`` would be correct, whereas `=1` isn't. What you write in the second paragraph is wrong.

Comment: Despite being accepted this answer is completely wrong. with lualatex your OT1 setting does nothing at all, as TU encoded fonts are being used. With pdflatex setting hyphenchar to 1 puts character 1 (which is a capital Delta) in every hyphenated word. Neither makes the image you show, with hyphens.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to improve something like that. Monospaced fonts usually have no interword stretchability and shrinkability, for they're mostly used to reproduce text where character alignment across rows is wanted and to achieve this the interword space is set to a rigid length as wide as the characters.

Such fonts usually don't allow hyphenation by disabling the `\hyphenchar` for them. With `pdflatex` and the default fonts in OT1 encoding we can read `ot1cmtt.fd` to see

```
\ProvidesFile{ot1cmtt.fd}
        [2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions]
\DeclareFontFamily{OT1}{cmtt}{\hyphenchar \font\m@ne}
\DeclareFontShape{OT1}{cmtt}{m}{n}
     {%
      <5><6><7><8>cmtt8<9>cmtt9%
      <10><10.95>cmtt10%
      <12><14.4><17.28><20.74><24.88>cmtt12%
      }{}
[...]
```

and `\m@ne` stands for `-1`. Most font will have no `\hyphenchar` declaration because in that case TeX will use the `\defaulthyphenchar`, that holds the value 45 (the font slot for the hyphen). The values for the interword spaces are instead stored in the `.tfm` file, and you can change them by acting on the appropriate `\fontdimen` parameters.

With `lualatex` instead, `tulmtt.fd` would be used:

```
\ProvidesFile{tulmtt.fd}
        [2021/07/23 v1.8a Standard LaTeX font definitions for Latin Modern]
\DeclareFontFamily{TU}{lmtt}{%
\hyphenchar \font\m@ne
\fontdimen3\font\z@
\fontdimen4\font\z@
}
[...]
```

so stretchability and shrinkability of interword spaces are forcibly removed.

However, you should remember that assignments to font parameters are inherently global: if you plan to use the monospaced font also for verbatim material or listings you'd need to revert those assignments at the end of your `minipage`.

I assume this is not the case.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newenvironment{monospacedquote}{%
  \begin{center}
  \begin{minipage}{5.75in}
  \LARGE
  \ttfamily
  \ifnum\hyphenchar\font=-1
    \hyphenchar\font=`-
    \fontdimen3\font=0.5\fontdimen2\font
    \fontdimen4\font=0.3\fontdimen2\font
    \fontdimen7\font=0.2\fontdimen2\font
  \fi
  \selectfont
  \leftskip=\fill
  \rightskip=-\leftskip
  \parfillskip=\stretch{2}%
}{\end{minipage}\end{center}}

\begin{document}

\begin{monospacedquote}
This is a minipage. The above line of commands justifies the text 
and centers the last line. Notice how awful it appears.
\end{monospacedquote}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: yes except OP is using luatex so TU not OT1 so the fd file used is different (but makes no matrial difference to the answer)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you've set big spaces between words by setting `\spaceskip`. I try to paraphrase your question: "I've set big spaces using TeX primitive `\spaceskip`, why I have big spaces?"

If you set less amount of spaces by `\spaceskip` then you get desired result. Moreover, I set hyphenchar for `\tt` font, this is mentioned here in other answers too.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{microtype}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
\textbf{This is a minipage. The above line of commands justifies the text and centers the last line. Notice how "nice" it appears.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}

\vspace*{25pt}

\begin{center}
\begin{LARGE}
\begin{minipage}{5.75in}\leftskip\fill\rightskip-\leftskip\parfillskip\stretch{2}%
%\spaceskip1em plus 1em \xspaceskip 1em plus 2em\relax %% ??? why this?
\spaceskip.3em plus .2em minus .1em \xspaceskip=\spaceskip {\tt\hyphenchar\font=`-}%
\texttt{I have, with the two above lines of commands, been able to justify the tttext in this minipage, as well as center the last line of output. This is what I want; however, the appearance does not seem as "nice" as the content of the above minipage.}
\end{minipage}
\end{LARGE}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you actually use LaTeX? I thought that was against your principles. `;-)`

Comment: I am not using LaTeX. The problem here isn't relevant to LaTeX. OP used **TeX primitive** to create big spaces between words and he asks why there are big spaces between words. This is key if of this thread.

Comment: I know, but the MWE you produced is LaTeX. Anyway, I was just joking. Be OpTimisTeX. ;-)